# How can I insert a period?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText` in application. When I press `space` key twice through soft keyboard, a period should be inserted in that `EditText`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you give a try and can you please post some code that you have tried before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) to your `EditText`.  And override `afterTextChanged()` method for it.
Now check `"  "` (Double space)  in that text of Edittext, if it contains just replace it with `"."`

Something like,

```
final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
 {
    if (editable.toString().contains("  "))
    {
     edit.setText(ed.getText().toString().trim());
     edit.append(".");
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: if edittext is empty then after pressing space twice dot " . " should not come. if it is not empty then pressing space bar " . " should come

Answer (score 0):

Try `InputFilter`.
These give you facility to check what text is input to your `EditText`.
so if you detect space twice(for that you can make counter) you can trim your text append . and show again.

you can change below code according to your needs.

```
InputFilter filter=new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
              { 
                  if(Character.isSpace(source.charAt(i)))
                      {
                      return " ";
                      }
                  else if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) 

                  { 
                          return ""; 
                  } 
              }   
            return null;
        }
    };


edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a couple booleans, add a listener onto the views and set them true for input and false for no input.
->if a user presses a key that is not allowed set them all to false. Otherwise, when they are all true, do the stuff you need to.
If you wanted to, you could add logic for checking the order.